# Child window outside of parent window. How?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to create a fancy borders around my main window. I tried several approaches - some works, some not. Now I want to do it with child windows. Child windows should move with a parent, resize. They should be semi-transparent (I want to draw a gradient with an alpha). Also they should be mouse transparent (click through).

I tried to create a child window with `WS_CHILD` flag. Unfortunately such a window can't be drawn outside of the main window. Moreover `WS_EX_LAYERED` can't be used with a child window in Windows 7. So this option immediately drops out.

Next I tried popup windows (i.e. with `WS_POPUP` flag). But everything become even worse - visual lags on minimizing/maximizing/restoring. If such a window have `WS_EX_LAYERED` flag then minimize animation for an owner no longer works (o_O) and so on.

Is it achievable at all what I want?

Comment: "*WS_EX_LAYERED can't be used with a child window*" - it can in Windows 8+.

Comment: Updated a post. I need this to work in Windows 7.

Comment: did you try getting the HDC of the main window and simply paint whatever border you want on the WM_PAINT message?

Comment: Grow your main window to include room for the border, and paint it yourself in your `WM_NCPAINT` message handler.

Comment: @DavidHaim, @IInspectable I did this before. In order to make a semitransparent background I have to use `UpdateLayeredWindow()` and this very very very slow. Anyway, in order to do what I want I just created additional windows without any relationship to main waindow. I just did it like VisualStudio fancy colored border done.